# Get the values of while loop using button with js

Tags: javascript, php

How can I get the values in the while loop using button with js?

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
      echo '<input type="text" name="sample" value="'.$row['sample'].'">';

    } 
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Use Ajax to get value from server end

Comment: you mean you want to read the contents of all the textboxes? Or something else? Please explain more clearly the situation and what your goal is

Comment: Is using jQuery an option?

Comment: my goal is to display all the values using a button click js

Comment: @Adder I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of textbox when you click on a button.

```
<input type="text" name="sample[]" value="abc" class="valueInput">
<input type="text" name="sample[]" value="xyz" class="valueInput">
<input type="text" name="sample[]" value="pqr" class="valueInput">
<input type="button" class="getValue" value="Get Value">
```

**Note: I have set the static input box you can make it dynamic but make sure please add the class as valueInput.**

Jquery Code.

```
$(document).on('click','.getValue',function(){
var valArr = [];
$(".valueInput").each(function(){
    valArr.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(valArr);
})
```

Comment: Welcome.i am happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the input field should indicate an array with [].

```
<form action="action.php" method="POST">
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
       echo '<input type="text" name="sample[]" value="'.$row['sample'].'">';
    } 
?><input type="submit">
</form>
```

action.php: (Processes the data on submit)

```
<?php
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($_POST['sample']);
      echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: It's correct but I'm trying to use javascript for getting the values.